# Chern Class of the Structure Sheaf of a Cartier Divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, intersection-theory

I'm reading 3264 and all that page 486. They calculate the chern class of the structure sheaf of a Cartier divisor.

Let $Y\subseteq X$ be a Cartier divisor. Then we have short exact sequence:
$$0\rightarrow \mathscr O_{X}(-Y)\rightarrow\mathscr O_{X}\rightarrow\mathscr O_Y\rightarrow 0$$

Hence $$c(\mathscr O_{Y}) = \frac{c(\mathscr O_X)}{c(\mathscr O_X(-Y))} = \frac{1}{1-[Y]}$$

I'm okay up to now. But then, they says:
$$\frac{1}{1-[Y]} = 1+[Y]$$
which confuses me. Shouldn't it be $1+[Y]+[Y]^2+\dots+[Y]^n$? How to see $[Y]^2 = 0$?
[image]

Comment: This must be a typo; your formula is correct.

Comment: @Sasha But in the explanation in the figure, it seems $c(\mathscr O_X) = 1+[Y]$ is something correct and special. They even emphasized that general subvariety may have codimension $>c$ terms. This seems to suggest Cartier divisors don't have codimension $>1$ term. That does not look like a typo.

Comment: This is strange indeed, but still, $[Y]^2 \ne 0$ in general (think of $Y$ being a line on a plane, for instance), so the formula in the book is incorrect.